Why does each page of Talmud end with the first word of the next page?
Within a perek, the central text of the Gemara/Mishnah ends with the first word of the next daf. For example, yesterday's daf ends with שנאמר, the first word of today's.
Why?
I've heard someone state that it's to make sure no pages are lost, but that concern applies to any other text as well, and I don't know of other texts that do this.

My siddur has this. I always assumed it was to make the flow easier when turning the page you would already be saying the next word

When assembling a gathering of pages it can be difficult to get the right page (each broad sheet has 4 pages on it and printing presses ran multiple images of a single page. Then the sheet had to eventually be realigned for another part and then collected and stitched together) The catch word makes it easier to know what page comes next in the signature.

These are called catchwords and as you said they are an error catching device to make sure all the pages go in the right order when being bound. They were common in many manuscripts and printed works a few hundred years ago.

You'd think that's what page numbers are for..... ;)

In Latin manuscripts copied in the British Isles as far back as the eighth or ninth century, numbering was sometimes used to ensure that individual sheets of parchment were collated in the correct order. Use of numbering was sparse. It’s been estimated that around 1450—just before the birth of printing in the West—less than 10 percent of manuscript books contained pagination.press. https://slate.com/human-interest/2015/02/page-numbers-where-did-they-come-from-and-are-they-even-useful-anymore.html

Perhaps the duplication of a word gives the reader a brief time to turn the page without breaking stride.
